# How to use named arguments in .NET/Link (COM interface to Excel)

Tags: .netlink

I am using Excel from Mathematica through .NET/Link (specifically using the COM interface).

The following C# code adds a sheet after the last sheet:

```
workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets.Count);
```

How can I use named arguments (After: in the example above) in .NET/Link to do the same?

Comment: When faced with this problem, I couldn't find an answer either, so I ended up having to create sheets in reverse order, as the default behaviour is for Excel to put new sheets in front of the last one. In the meantime have you found a solution? If not, how can this question be bumped up? Does a new one have to be submitted?

Comment: I have not found a solution to this.

Comment: I see this is an old question, but I'd like to know the answer to this as well. Being able to do something like `Workbooks("book1").Close SaveChanges:=False` would be very helpful to manipulate notebooks more easily.