# Exporting *formatted* Excel workbooks

Tags: export, formatting, interoperability, excel

I export *Mathematica* tables to Excel every day, for sharing reports with non-*Mathematica* users. It exports the values without flaw, but ignores any formatting. Consider the following:

```
colHeadings = {"datum 1", "datum 2"};
rowHeadings = {"yesterday", "today", "tomorrow"};
data = {{1.2, 2.4}, {1.3, 2.1}, {1.31, 2.0}};
dataT = Prepend[Partition[Flatten[Transpose[{rowHeadings, data}]], 3],
   Flatten[{"", colHeadings}]];
```

I would like to export this to Excel with a modest amount of formatting – column borders would suffice. It's easy to format the data in *Mathematica*, some examples follow:

```
table1 = TableForm[dataT]

table2 = TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {rowHeadings, colHeadings}]

grid1 = Grid[dataT, Alignment -> {{Right, {Decimal}}}, 
  Dividers -> {All, {True, True, {False}, True}}]
```

But no matter which of these I export to Excel, it comes out the same, as a raw data table.

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "dataT.xlsx"}], dataT]

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", 
   "table1.xlsx"}], table1]

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", 
   "table2.xlsx"}], table2] (* omits the column and row headings *)

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "grid1.xlsx"}], grid1]
```

Any suggestions, or am I asking for something that *Mathematica* just can't do?

Comment: you maybe want to look at this: https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/excel_link/

Comment: @george2079  Oof. I hope I don't have to pay over $200 just to add borders around cells in Excel (if the Excel Link can even do that, it's unclear).

Comment: @MichaelStern It is possible, but not out of the box. You have to use JLink and fiddle around.
`Export[xlsFile = 
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "dataT.xlsx"}], dataT];
finstream = JavaNew["java.io.FileInputStream", xlsFile];
myXlsxWorkbook = 
JavaNew["org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook", finstream];
style = myXlsxWorkbook@createCellStyle[];
cu = LoadJavaClass["org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil"]` and so on. Now you have to read the XSSF API. It is painful, but possible. No time right now.

Comment: @RolfMertig What is createCellStyle[]?

Comment: In the past (more than 10 years), I solved this problem by calling Excel via NETLink (Com Interface to Excel). It's not immediate and there are limitations, particularly [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63131/5467)

Comment: @MichaelStern it is a Java method described [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createCellStyle()):

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15786/280