# Preserving mathematica formatting when exporting to Excel

Tags: export, fonts, excel

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "c"}}
```

I would like to format the list such that whenever "c" occurs as the last element in a sublist, I would like to change the "c"'s font color to Red.

I would then like to export this array to Excel, generating a 3-by-3 table and preserving the font color change. Is this even possible?

Comment: Formatting the c when it's at the end of the sublist is straightforward: `lis /. {v__, "c"} :> {v, Style["c", Red]}`. Unfortunately, I don't know whether the formatting can be exported to Excel.

Comment: As an update, the short answer on exporting formatted content to Excel seems to be "perhaps, if you have a lot of time on your hands, but certainly not easily". See [Exporting *formatted* Excel workbooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129673/27951) and [How to write data from Mathematica to an existing formatted Excel file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15786/27951) and [ExcelLink: How to change cell properties like font family, size and borders?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130437/27951) (the latter really being about *avoiding* the need for ExcelLink).